# Presenting only a single custom app via the Salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

Documentation such as [Salesforce1 App Guidelines](http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/assets/S1AppGuidelines.pdf) typically shows a "Navigation Menu" akin to the tabs of the non-mobile UI.

Is it possible to configure specific profile users so that this menu is not present at all, essentially limiting the user to one small set of custom app pages? The use case is portal access through some custom UI, so the availability of communities features may also be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not - you can cut down the menu, but your changes will apply to all users rather than a specific profile.  For example, the only way to remove Recent, Feed, People, Groups and Today is via the Mobile Navigation setup, but this applies to the entire org and doesn't allow you to specify different versions per user or profile.  There are also some menu items that you have no control over - settings and logout functionality for example. You can make your app the default for Salesforce1 by placing it at the top of the mobile navigation menu.

You'd need to look at a custom mobile app for this I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. We have created a custom mobile app for this but don't want to keep going with that if there is a simpler way using the core platform.